# Using Global Temporary Table in Subquery gives NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery

I am using following query.

```
SELECT  SYSDATE,(SELECT P_PRICE_OPEN FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE WHERE FSYM_ID='P8R3C2-R' AND P_DATE='22-OCT-18' AND P_VOLUME<>0 AND ROWNUM=1) FROM DUAL;
```

GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE is global temporary table loaded with values when i have executed a function related to it. This GTT preserves rows after commit. This query gives me correct results.

But, If i run the query

```
SELECT WEEK_END, WEEK_START, 
        (SELECT P_PRICE_OPEN FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE WHERE P_DATE=WEEK_START) AS WEEKS_OPEN_PRICE,
        (SELECT MAX(P_PRICE_HIGH) FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE WHERE FSYM_ID=FID AND P_DATE<=WEEK_END 
                AND P_DATE>=WEEK_START AND P_VOLUME<>0) AS WEEKLY_HIGH,
         (SELECT MIN(P_PRICE_LOW) FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE WHERE FSYM_ID=FID AND P_DATE<=WEEK_END 
                AND P_DATE>=WEEK_START AND P_VOLUME<>0) AS WEEKLY_LOW,
        (SELECT SUM(P_VOLUME) FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE WHERE FSYM_ID=FID AND P_DATE<=WEEK_END 
                AND P_DATE>=WEEK_START AND P_VOLUME<>0) AS WEEKLY_VOLUME,
        P_PRICE 
FROM (
       SELECT ROWNUM,FID,WEEK_END,P_VOLUME,P_PRICE,
                 (SELECT P_DATE FROM FP_V2_FP_BASIC_PRICES WHERE FSYM_ID=FID AND P_DATE>=TRUNC(WEEK_END, 'IW') AND P_VOLUME<>0 AND ROWNUM=1) AS WEEK_START
       FROM (
              SELECT 
                    ROWNUM,FSYM_ID AS FID, WEEK_END,P_VOLUME, P_PRICE,P_PRICE_OPEN,P_PRICE_HIGH,P_PRICE_LOW
              FROM (
                     SELECT ROWNUM,FSYM_ID,P_DATE AS WEEK_END, P_PRICE,P_VOLUME, P_PRICE_OPEN,P_PRICE_HIGH,P_PRICE_LOW,
                            CASE 
                                 WHEN (TO_CHAR(P_DATE,'D') >= AVG(TO_CHAR(P_DATE,'D')) OVER (order by P_DATE DESC rows between 1 preceding and current row) and ROWNUM>=1)  or TO_CHAR(P_DATE,'D')=6
                                 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END AS WEEKFLAG
                     FROM(
                           SELECT * FROM TABLE (ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')) WHERE P_VOLUME<>0
                         ) 
                    )WHERE WEEKFLAG=1
             )
      );
```

It gives me NULL in WEEKS_OPEN_PRICE,WEEKLY_HIGH,WEEKLY_LOW,WEEKLY_VOLUME.
Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @XING I do get the queries if i use select * FROM GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE; No of rows are 8000+.

Comment: You query is really hard to understand is not very well written. If you show what you have as input and what is your expected output then it would be easier for anyone to reply.

Comment: @XING there is function called ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R') which loads values to the GTT named as GTT_ADJ_PRICE_TABLE. And from same i am trying to get 11 and 40 weeks averages and weekly hihg's and low's. If still not understood i can try to make my query short and keep necessary part only.

Comment: Readability is a feature. Your query is badly laid out which means we can't read it without scrolling. Also it is entirely in upper-case, which makes it harder to read. Your query seems unnecessarily complicated, featuring as it does a suspicious amount of nested subqueries. Finally you have not explained the business logic you're trying to implement. If you want people to spend their time helping you, you should reduce the level of challenge involved in comprehending your query. You never know, re-writing your query so it's easy to understand may lead you to the answer you seek.

Comment: @APC I have updated the query for better understanding. Apologies for the previous input.

Comment: Did you check if your table function `ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')` returning any rows?

Comment: if I were you, I'd check what values of fid are being passed into the GTT - do rows exist that meet the criteria for those fids?

Comment: Yes they do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `WITH` clause. I hope a below query works. I don't have possibility to check.

```
WITH adjustedPrice AS (
   SELECT *
     FROM TABLE(adjusted_price('P8R3C2-R'))
    WHERE p_volume <> 0
      AND TO_CHAR(p_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') 
)
SELECT ap.week,
       ap.week_start,
       ap.week_end,
       ap.weeks_high_price,
       ap.weeks_low_price,
       ap.weekly_volume,
       ws.p_price_open AS weeks_open_price,
       we.p_price      AS weeks_close_price
  FROM (
         SELECT TRUNC(p_date, 'IW') AS week,
                TRUNC(MIN(p_date))  AS week_start,
                TRUNC(MAX(p_date))  AS week_end,
                MAX(p_price_high)   AS weeks_high_price,
                MIN(p_price_low)    AS weeks_low_price,
                SUM(p_volume)       AS weekly_volume
           FROM adjustedPrice
          GROUP BY TRUNC(p_date, 'IW')
        ) ap
 INNER JOIN adjustedPrice ws ON ws.p_date = ap.week_start 
 INNER JOIN adjustedPrice we ON we.p_date = ap.week_end
ORDER BY week DESC;
```

Comment: That did worked for me. Just remove **AND TO_CHAR(p_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')** and edit your answer. I checked in the database i don't have any Saturday or Sunday dates. Your query is also time efficient. Thanks a lot for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post as a comment. But it wont fit there thats why writing it as an answer.

I tried this code to get the week start, end , weeks high price, weeks low price, weekly volume.

```
              select
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW') as week,
                        min(trunc("P_DATE")) as week_start,
                        max(trunc("P_DATE")) as week_end,
                        MAX(P_PRICE_HIGH) AS WEEKS_HIGH_PRICE,
                        MIN(P_PRICE_LOW) AS WEEKS_LOW_PRICE,
                        SUM(P_VOLUME) AS WEEKLY_VOLUME
            from TABLE 
                        (ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')) 
            WHERE 
                        P_VOLUME<>0 AND to_char("P_DATE", 'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
            group by 
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW')
            ORDER BY 
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW') DESC;
```

That gave me results in hardly 2-4 seconds. But i want to get the weeks open price where date will be equal to WEEK_START and weeks closing price where date will be equal to WEEK_END.

I tried following approach for the same. But its taking too much time (like 300+ seconds).

```
SELECT 
        WEEK,WEEK_START, WEEK_END, WEEKS_HIGH_PRICE,WEEKS_LOW_PRICE,WEEKLY_VOLUME,
        (SELECT P_PRICE_OPEN FROM TABLE  (ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')) WHERE P_VOLUME<>0 AND P_DATE=WEEK_START) AS WEEKS_OPEN_PRICE,
        (SELECT P_PRICE FROM TABLE  (ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')) WHERE P_VOLUME<>0 AND P_DATE=WEEK_END) AS WEEKS_CLOSE_PRICE
FROM
        (
            select
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW') as week,
                        min(trunc("P_DATE")) as week_start,
                        max(trunc("P_DATE")) as week_end,
                        MAX(P_PRICE_HIGH) AS WEEKS_HIGH_PRICE,
                        MIN(P_PRICE_LOW) AS WEEKS_LOW_PRICE,
                        SUM(P_VOLUME) AS WEEKLY_VOLUME
            from TABLE 
                        (ADJUSTED_PRICE('P8R3C2-R')) 
            WHERE 
                        P_VOLUME<>0 AND to_char("P_DATE", 'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
            group by 
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW')
            ORDER BY 
                        trunc("P_DATE", 'IW') DESC
        );
```

**If anybody can help me to improve the output time is most welcome.**